# Pandas: return a Dataframe with multiple aggregate values conditioned on another value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do something well beyond my Pandas level and have spent far too much time getting this wrong. In this example I need to return individual Dataframes for each of the teams. The dataframes would show the mean cost, mean area, and sum of size, for each grade.

Because I need to produce separate tables, I probably need to pass single team names into a function over and over. To be clear, I'm happy to pass the team names into a function (or similar) manually to produce each table.

```
    team      grade   cost   area   size
0   man utd   1       52300  5      1045
1   chelsea   3       52000  42     957
2   arsenal   2       25000  20     1099
3   man utd   1       61600  20     1400
4   man utd   2       43000  43     1592
5   arsenal   2       23400  78     1006
6   man utd   2       52300  89     987
7   chelsea   4       62000  30     849
8   arsenal   1       62000  46     973
9   arsenal   2       73000  78     1005
```

The man utd dataframe would look like this for example:

```
grade  mean_cost    mean_area   size
1      56590        12.5        2445
2      47650        66          2579
```

Comment: And...? What is your question? Surely you have code, but you're stuck somewhere, so give us something specific to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby/agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to group by both the `team` and `grade`, and the aggregate the `cost`, `area` and `size` columns. Note that `agg` can accept a `dict` whose keys are column names and whose values are aggregation functions (such as `mean` or `sum`). Thus you can specify aggregation functions on a per-column basis.

```
In [120]: df.groupby(['team', 'grade']).agg({'cost':'mean', 'area':'mean', 'size':'sum'}).rename(columns={'cost':'mean_cost', 'area':'mean_area'})
Out[120]: 
               size     mean_cost  mean_area
team    grade                               
arsenal 1       973  62000.000000  46.000000
        2      3110  40466.666667  58.666667
chelsea 3       957  52000.000000  42.000000
        4       849  62000.000000  30.000000
man utd 1      2445  56950.000000  12.500000
        2      2579  47650.000000  66.000000
```

`groupby` returns an iterable. Therefore, to make a dict mapping team names to DataFrames you could use:

```
dfs = {team:grp for team, grp in result.reset_index().groupby('team')}
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'area': [5, 42, 20, 20, 43, 78, 89, 30, 46, 78],
     'cost': [52300, 52000, 25000, 61600, 43000, 23400, 52300, 62000, 62000, 73000], 
     'grade': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2], 'size': [1045, 957, 1099, 1400, 1592, 1006, 987, 849, 973, 1005], 
     'team': ['man utd', 'chelsea', 'arsenal', 'man utd', 'man utd', 'arsenal', 'man utd', 'chelsea', 'arsenal', 'arsenal']})

result =  df.groupby(['team', 'grade']).agg({'cost':'mean', 'area':'mean', 'size':'sum'}).rename(columns={'cost':'mean_cost', 'area':'mean_area'})

dfs = {team:grp.drop('team', axis=1) 
       for team, grp in result.reset_index().groupby('team')}

for team, grp in dfs.items():
    print('{}:\n{}\n'.format(team, grp))
```

yields

```
chelsea:
   grade  mean_cost  mean_area  size
2      3      52000         42   957
3      4      62000         30   849

arsenal:
   grade     mean_cost  mean_area  size
0      1  62000.000000  46.000000   973
1      2  40466.666667  58.666667  3110

man utd:
   grade  mean_cost  mean_area  size
4      1      56950       12.5  2445
5      2      47650       66.0  2579
```

---

Beware that for better performance try to avoid breaking up
DataFrames into smaller DataFrames, because once you use a dict or a list, you
are forced to use Python loops instead of the faster implicit C-compiled loops
used by Pandas/NumPy methods.

So for computation try to stick with the `result` DataFrame.  Use the `dfs` dict
only if you have to do something like print the DataFrames separately.

Comment: Most insightful and informative answer I've ever had on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: Is there also a way to print the dataframes individually in the pandas table style. Ideally need to screenshot them for presentation purposes.

Comment: To help build Stackoverflow's stable of good questions paired with good answers, please ask this as a new question.

Comment: Agreed: question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719812/pandas-how-to-reference-and-print-multiple-dataframes-as-html-tables)