# Display several summary statistic tables

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, summary

Does anyone know if it is possible to tell python to display more than one summary statistic tables in the output?

This is my input:

```
efw2016_mc.describe()
efw1990_mc.describe()
efw1970_mc.describe()
```

But the output only shows one of the tables. Is it possible to display all three in one output?

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes @killian95 . I'm usind pandas

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719812/pandas-how-to-reference-and-print-multiple-dataframes-as-html-tables . You can group your frames into a dict and loop a display on all of them.

Comment: calling describe multiple times works fine for me when running from command line. How are you running the script?

Comment: Why not use good old `print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Jupyter notebook you can use `display()`:

```
display(efw2016_mc.describe())
display(efw1990_mc.describe())
display(efw1970_mc.describe())
```

Or use concat() to make one dataframe:

```
a = efw2016_mc.describe()
b = efw1990_mc.describe()
c = efw1970_mc.describe()

df = pd.concat([a,b,c])
df
```